# Is it posible to use request parameters in spring webflow view?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am newbie in Spring Webflow and I am migrating and old Java MVC application to Spring MVC + WebFlow.

Navigation in our old application worked with URLs like this `/MyServlet?action=myAction&status=1` and we need to mantain them in the new application. So we have create a Controller that controls all requests to MyServlet with

```
@RequestMapping(value="/MyServlet", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
```

In this controller we have old servlet code who execute actions. This solution permit us use old code under Spring control.

Now we want to use WebFlow, but all views are expressed with URLs mention above and when I try to create a flow, it seems to be invalid. I have the following error:

> The reference to entity "action" must end with the ';' delimiter

This is my XML flow file:

```
<view-state id="idIn" view="/MyServlet?action=myAction&status=1">
    <transition on="list" to="idList" />
</view-state>

<view-state id="idList" view="/MyServlet?action=myAction&status=2">
    <transition on="new" to="idNew" />
</view-state>

<view-state id="idNew" view="/MyServlet?action=myAction&status=3">
    <transition on="out" to="idOut" />
</view-state>

<end-state id="idOut" view="/MyServlet">
</end-state>
```

Is it possible to use URL with parameters in Spring WebFLow? How could I do it?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spring WebFlow has its own URL structure, with all states within a flow sharing a single URL for the whole flow. So you're not going to be able to maintain your current URL structure and use Spring WebFlow at the same time.

Thus, individual states within the flow are not directly accessible, even if you could transform the URLs with something like mod_rewrite, you'd be trying to jump into the middle of a flow, which is not how Spring WebFlow works.

Also, the `view` in the `view-state` is supposed to be a view-rendering technology like a JSP or Tile definition. It's an internal reference to a specific view, not the URL visible to the external user.

Answer (score 0):

```
The reference to entity "action" must end with the ';' delimiter
```

This error uses to appear when character `&` is written to pass paramters in the URL. Just write `&amp;` instead that character and the error should be fixed.

Hope this helps.